# ruby inheritance. Converting one object into another

Tags: ruby

I do not know the terminology of what I am trying to do so googling it has proven very hard.

I have 2 ruby classes.

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base

end

class B < A

end
```

class A is what hits the database. There is a column in class A that stores the intended class name. In this example the value of that column in class A would be 'b'.

My desire is to find a way to call A, and actually get B. My thought being there will be more than just B in the future I could end up having C, D, and even E. All of these classes could require unique methods.

Comment: Rails has more ou less that with Single Table Inheritance. See more here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord::Base-label-Single+table+inheritance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rails' Single Table Inheritance can help you: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord::Base-label-Single+table+inheritance

Answer (score 2):

This is called STI (Single Table Inheritance). The correct way to implement it is to add a column named `type` to the base class table. Rails will use this column to know what class to instantiate for a given record. 
For example lets assume we have three classes, `Person`, `Teacher` and `Student`. `Person` is the base class and `Teacher` and `Student` inherits from it. In this case we implement it as follows:

Migration:

```
class CreatePeople < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
    create_table :people do |t|
      ... # person attributes name, birthday ...
      ... # Student specific attributes
      ... # Teacher specific attributes 
      t.string :type # this will be Student, Teacher or Even Person.

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Models

```
# Person
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
end

# Teacher
class Teacher < Person
end

# Student
class Student < Person
end
```

so if you create a new student

```
student = Student.new(name: 'studentx',...)
student.save
```

than get it throught the `Person` class

```
person = Person.first
puts person.type # => Student
```

When you create a new student, and to be sure that its attributes are set correctly, so that for example, a student does not have teacher's specific attributes set. you just filter them in the controller through strong parameters( assuming this is a Rails application)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to do that in pure Ruby would be to return B from a method called on A.

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  def b
    return B.new(self)
  end
end

class B
  def initialize(a)
    @a = a
  end

  # if you need to get methods belonging to A 
  def method_missing(*args, &block)
    @a.send(*args, &block)
  end
end
```